# How to malloc these structures?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, malloc, sizeof

```
struct atom {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  double mass;
};

struct molecule {
  struct atom *member;
  int natoms;
};

struct system {
  struct molecule *fragment;
  int nfrags
};

struct system sys;
sys.nfrags=get_number_of_fragments;
????
```

The system has some number of molecules, each of which has some number of atoms. I don't know how to allocate these things. If I allocate sys.fragment first, it seems like the sizeof(molecule) is undefined since I haven't yet defined the number of atoms (so how can it have a size?). If I try to define the number of atoms first, how do I specify which fragment I'm mallocing for?

I have functions that will return the number of atoms for any molecule/fragment as well as the number of fragments, but am stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: Might be worth looking at how variable size arrays are often implemented in c; `realloc' is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK sizeof(X) cannot be "undefined". In this example, sizeof(molecule) is well defined as the amount of memory it takes to store one molecule instance: One atom Pointer (Note: not the size of any array that you may put here, just the size of the pointer) and one int. So it is perfectly fine to do it the first way and allocate your  sys.fragment first:

```
sys.fragment = malloc(sys.nfrag * sizeof(sys.fragment));
```

Comment: I would write this as `sys.fragment = malloc(sys.nfrag * sizeof sys.fragment);` (after taking care to ensure that the multiplication doesn't overflow).

Answer (score 1):

```
sys.fragment = calloc(sys.nfrag, sizeof sys.fragmemt[0]);
```

or

```
sys.fragment = malloc(sys.nfrag * sizeof sys.fragment[0]);
```

when performance matters (but do not forget the check for overflow!).

Answer (score 0):

`malloc(sizeof(system))` Easy as that

Comment: You're saying that I should do something like sys.fragment=(struct moluecule *)sizeof(system)?

Comment: Basically. And so on and so forth. But what I would probably do is set up another variable that equals `sys.fragment` so you don't end up with a really long confusing statement

Comment: @Pinyaka Absolutly not! you are casting an integer to a pointer there, which will fail immensely when you try to put anything there.

Comment: @Quirliom you are absolutely right. I just glanced at the statement but missed the cast.

Answer (score -1):

You basically have a:

```
size = X;
first = malloc(X * sizeof(First));
first->second = malloc( N * sizeof(Second));
```

and so on